# How to loop through following blocks using vanilla JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner at JavaScript and I am trying to make a quiz game, in order to learn manipulate DOM. I know there are similar questions to this, unfortunately I could not find an answer to my situation.

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Test your knowledge</h1>
  <form class="box" id="quizBox1">
    <div class="question1">
      <p>What is the name of George?</p>
      <div class="inputs">
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="wrong">Tom
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="correct">George
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="wrong">John<br>
        <input type="submit" name="quiz1" class="button" id="answer" onclick="return quiz();">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form class="box" id="quizBox2">
    <div class="question2">
      <p>Which one is blue?</p>
      <div class="inputs">
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="quiz2" value="wrong">Banana
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="quiz2" value="correct">Sky
        <input id="answer" type="radio" name="quiz2" value="wrong">Red BMW<br>
        <input type="submit" name="quiz2" class="button" id="answer" onclick="return quiz();">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Basically I have two forms with different sets of questions (but I want to add more once I figure this out). I already managed to find out how to track if the correct answer has been chosen and add number of correct answers to show at the end.

And this JavaScript:

```
function quiz () {
  var amountCorrect = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i <=12; i++)
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz"+1);
  // var questions = document.getElementByIdName("quizBox"+1);

  for(var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
    var radio = radios[j];
    if (radio.value === "correct" && radio.checked) {
      alert("correct");
      amountCorrect ++;
      questions.style("display", "none");
    } else if (radio.checked && radio.value != "correct") {
      alert("not");
    }
  }
  alert(amountCorrect);
}
```

My issue here is that I can not figure out how to swap to another block of questions, once current one is answered. I tried setting up a new variable each time and display the next block of questions, while hiding the others, but I could not find a way to make it work. I would like to achieve this in vanilla JS, without using jQuery, if possible. Any help is appreciated, even if it is something that helps me to get on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small change to your quiz function. Add a parameter which allows it to know which set it radio buttons to look at.

```
function quiz(p) {
.....getElementsByName(p);
}
```

Then call it for different sets.
    quiz("quiz1");

Also to show and hide a form, you can do something like

```
let a = document.gelElementById("quizBox1);
a.style.display = "none";
```

And change the property to `block` when you need to show it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common pattern for this.

If you have a bunch of quiz blocks like

```
<div class='quiz' id='quiz1'>
...
</div>

<div class='quiz' id='quiz2'>
...
</div>
```

First select them all and make them hidden

```
let quizzes = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz");
for (let i = 0; i < quizzes.length; i++) {
  quizzes[i].style.display = "hidden";
}
```

Then set the one you want to show

```
document.getElementById(quizIWantToShow).style.display = "block";
```